# Changing line height within the dot-points in a list (NOT between the dot-points)

Tags: html, css, spacing

```
 <ul style="text-align: left; line-height: 85%; color: #BDACAB; font-size: 18px; font-family: Verdana">
<li>“I swear to god I had something for this.” - Archer</li>
<li>“You’re not my supervisor!” - Cheryl</li>
<li>“Phrasing.” - Archer</li>
<li>“Because that’s how you get ants.” - Various</li>
<li>“Read a book!” - Archer</li>
<li>Lana...Lana! Lana!! ...Come on, if you don't answer I'm going to scream as loud as I possibly ...La"-- "What?!" "I'm sorry, I meant "Mrs. Archer"</li>
<li>"Oh irony..." - Archer</li>
<li>"Double irony" - Archer</li>
<li>Who...or Whom?</li>
</ul>
```

Ok, so I can only use inline-css styles to accomplish this. I can't figure out how to increase the spacing between lines within a single dot-point. I can already adjust the spacing between the dot-points with 'line-height'.

It's where the text is too long for the box and wraps down onto the next line...this spacing is too close. An example is the following text (for some reason I can't post an image):

Any ideas?

Comment: question is not clear, I'm getting what do you want (+5) for add image.

Comment: Okay, so there's a an unordered list with a number of dot points in it. I can control the vertical spacing between these dot-points with line-height (line-height: 85%;) easily enough. That's NOT my issue.

The issue I have is that I wan to increase the line-height within the individual dot-point, so that when the text wraps around within the element, it doesn't overlap/sit too close. It would be much easier to explain with an image...

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure if this answers your question, but put some top and bottom padding around the `<li>` tags? and put a `<br>` (probably could use something better to break the line up or use a container in div tags

```
<li>Lana...Lana! Lana!! ...Come on, if you don't answer I'm going <br>
to scream as loud as I possibly ...La"-- "What?!" "I'm sorry, I meant "Mrs. Archer"</li>
```

Comment: I can't use div tags for this unfortunately. The only thing I have access to is html5 and inline css (and they're not standardised for some reason).

I tried adding breaks before, no luck...

I tried adding individual styling (style="padding: 10px 0px;") into the <li> tags if that's where you're saying to add the padding, no luck. Adding it to the next layer up wouldn't help with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround which involves using a 'float' within a  'float' ...float-ception! It's the best result I've had so far...

```
<ul style="width: 100%; text-align: left; line-height: 90%; color: #BDACAB; font-size: 18px; font-family: Verdana">
<ul style="float: left; width: 35%; text-align: left; margin: 0px 0px 0px -35px; padding: 0px 10px 0px 0px; list-style-type: none;">
<li> <b>Monday: </b></li>
<li> <b>Tuesday: </b></li>
<li> <b>Wednesday: </b></li>
<li><b>Thursday: </b></li>
<li> <b>Friday: </b></li>
<li> <b>Saturday: </b></li>
<li> <b>Sunday: </b></li>
</ul>
<ul style="float: right; width: 55%; text-align: left; margin: -15px 0px 0px 0px; list-style-type: none;">
<li>Show</li>
<li>Show</li>
<li>Show</li>
<li>No Show</li>
<li>Show</li>
<li>Show</li>
<li>No Show</li>
</ul>
</ul>
```